# Preposition as and in used

Tags: prepositions

I am confused which one of the below sentences is correct.

1.Mohan works in the Hotel as a waiter.

2.Mohan works as a waiter in the Hotel.

Comment: Both sentences are correct. There might be a slight difference in emphasis.

Comment: Gustavson, could you describe what is the emphasis.

Comment: I meant to say, a difference in focus. I imagine that in sentence (1) the interlocutor might already know that Mohan works in the hotel, and the speaker places "as a waiter" in end position to clarify what he does at the hotel: *Mohan works in the hotel as a waiter, not as a receptionist.* By contrast, in sentence (2) the new information might be that he works as a waiter in the hotel, not in a bar.